# Multi-country app with separate content for each country next js 14

Tags: next.js, i18next, catalog, next.js14

I am working on a next js 14 website [to publish catalog of big shops](https://flipini.fr/) currently targetting only french but now i want to target more countries like Germany, Spain, England, Morocco... in the domain flipini.com where i want each country in a sub-path /de for germany, /es fro spain.... where every country has it's own language an it's own content of shops and catalogues.
what is the best way to do handle content separation based on the countries ids.
nb: my api already handle country separation content. just need to separate them in the frontend.
nb2: it will be great if no 3rd party code.

I did try i18n but there is example where multiple countries have the same language but different content. Also there are cases the abv of the country doesn't match the abv of the country language.